# Properties of joint entropy

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

I'm trying to show the following, but am stuck

For discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, show 
$$H(X,Y)\geq \max\{H(X),H(Y)\}$$
where $H$ represents entropy

Answer (score 1):

By standard properties

$$H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y\mid X) = H(Y) + H(X\mid Y)$$

Assume that $\max\{H(X),H(Y)\} = H(X)$.
Then you require

$$H(X,Y) \ge \;H(X) \iff H(X) + H(Y\mid X) \ge \;H(X) \iff H(Y\mid X) \ge\; 0$$

which holds true since Entropy (related to discrete random variables, and in contrast to Differential Entropy that refers to continuous random variables), is always positive.

An analogous result will obtain if you assume $\max\{H(X),H(Y)\} = H(Y)$. QED

Comment: The answer is great, but the way you used the implication signs disturbs me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate a bit, because I am not sure that I fully understand it?

Comment: After you say "then you require" you have a chain of implications, but what you really want are the reverse implications. A quick fix would be to change them all to if and only if.

Comment: I agree with that , and just made the change.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

You should show that $H(X,Y) \ge H(X)$ and $H(X,Y) \ge H(Y)$

$P(X=x_i)=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}P(x_i,y_j)$

$H(X,Y)-H(X) = (-\sum\limits_{i,j}P(x_i,y_j)\log P(x_i,y_j))-(-\sum\limits_{i}P(x_i)\log P(x_i))\\ =(-\sum\limits_{i,j}P(x_i,y_j)\log P(x_i,y_j))-(-\sum\limits_{i,j}P(x_i,y_j)\log P(x_i))\\=-\sum\limits_{i,j}P(x_i,y_j)(\log P(x_i,y_j)-\log P(x_i))$